# Django queryset filter with iregex returns all objects even if filter condition is not matched

Tags: python, django, django-models

I need to query database to get list of users based on case insensitive regex search of emails.

```py
User.objects.filter(email__iregex=f'({"|".join(emails)})')
```

Here emails is a list containing email ids of users. When emails is an empty list the above returns all users from the database. I am unable to figure out why this is occuring? Ideally when emails is empty list, empty queryset should be returned. Can somebody tell me what is wrong with above code.

Comment: This is perfectly normal, since the regex has no begin/start anchor, and thus an empty regex matches *everything*.

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly normal, since the regex has no begin/start anchor, and thus an empty regex matches *everything*. You can add anchors `^` (the start anchor) and `$` (the end anchor) like:

```
User.objects.filter(email__iregex=f'^({'|'.join(emails)})$')
```

but still the problem is not solved completely. If the email adress contains a dot (`.`) that means "matches any character"), if it contains a question mark (`?`), it will be interpreted as an optional part. You can escape these with [**`re.escape(…)`** [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape):

```
from re import escape as rescape

escaped_emails = '|'.join(map(rescape, emails))
User.objects.filter(email__iregex=f'^({escaped_emails})$')
```